# Using a direct proof, how should I approach this question?

Tags: proof-writing

For integers $x$ and $y$, if $xy$ is even, then either $x$ or $y$ must be even.

I know how to solve this in both a contradictive and contrapositive manner but can not quite figure out how to solve it with a direct proof. An identical problem was solved via a contrapositive proof 9 years ago on this site, however even looking through that did not help me with a direct proof. I find myself having to assume that the proposition is true in order to prove it true, which I am not allowed to do.

Comment: Use the prime factorisation of $x$ and $y$

Comment: @VincentBatens Isn't that circular?

Comment: Careful with “either $a$ or $b$,” as that often refers to the exclusive or.